# Why do I get undefined here?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

```
function myFunc() {
    var word = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
    var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("Text2").value);
    var numstr = num.split(",");
    var wordstr = word.split("");
    for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    }
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += (wordstr[(numstr[i])-1]);

}
```

did I parseInt incorrectly? I've tried toString(), with ParseInt it doesn't do anything and without it I get 'undefined'

Comment: What is in the input with id `Text2`? Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why would `num` (which is now a Number due to calling `parseInt`) have a `split` method? You can make this a MCVE by having your function take two arguments (text1, text2) and returning the value you want to put in "myDiv". You should include an example of what text1 and text2 would be (I assume two strings, one of which can be converted to a number), and an example of your expected output

Comment: I don't think you should use parseInt. From your code, it seems that Text2 holds some numbers with comma and you want to split this text to get an array of those numbers.

Comment: Also you should do some validation, to make sure the numstr array has at least the amount of elements that wordstr has, or else it will fail inside the for expression where you do this: wordstr[(numstr[i])-1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parseInt()` function parses a string and returns an integer.
You check your input with id `"Text2"` and show your HTML here to clearify the issue.

Comment: Your'e right, the input is "2,3,4,3" for example, and I reckon parseInt doesn't like commas, but I removed that and tried changing wordstr[parseInt(numstr[i])-1] basically parseInting there and it just gives me a blank answer.

Comment: If it is works for you, then accept my answer to close this question @זיורוזוב

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your problem, it looks like you are misunderstanding how parseInt() works. Despite the misleading name, it will read your string character by character, attempting to create an integer. It will stop as soon as it finds a character that can't be part of an integer.

If you pass it "1,2,3,4" then it will read the 2 fine, but as a comma cannot be parsed as part of an integer, it will return the **number** 2.  It doesn't make sense to call split on a number.

As others have said, you really need to give us more details for us to be able to help, but I suspect a large part of the problem is not understanding what some of these functions do.

Maybe you could explain what you're trying to achieve, then we can help you get there. Right now, your code isn't clear enough without extra information.